# change hidden name attribute after radio button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the need to change the `name=' '` attribute of a hidden input when one of the radio buttons in a group is selected.

```
<input type="hidden" name="OptionName2" value="Premium Bundle Addons">
<input type="hidden" name="" value="PremiumBundleAddon">

HBO & Cinemax & Starz Package
<input type="radio" name="OptionValue2" value="3ITEM-HBO-CIN-STAR"><br />
HBO & Cinemax & Showtime Package
<input type="radio" name="OptionValue2" value="3ITEM-HBO-SHO-CIN"><br />
HBO & Showtime & Cinemax & Starz Package
<input type="radio" name="OptionValue2" value="ALL-HBO-SHO-CIN-STAR">
```

The `name=""` needs to change to `name="ADD"` when one of these radio buttons is clicked.

Here is what I have tried but I really struggle with javascript. If anyone could help dumb it down for me that would be amazing!

```
$(":radio").click(function () {
var inputValue = $this.val();
$(":hidden[name='opt2']").name() = "ADD";
});
});
```

Comment: The way forms are designed assumes that the names of inputs will remain constant, and that the values will be the things that change. Have you considered making the `name="PremiumBundleAddon"` and the `value=""`, then changing the `value` to `ADD` when the buttons are clicked? Or at the least, keeping `name="ADD"` and setting the value from empty to `PremiumBundleAddon`?

Comment: that is not a proper jQuery expression `$(":hidden[name='opt2']").name() = "ADD";` . use this instead `$(":hidden[name='OptionName2']").attr("name", "ADD");` and are you sure that dynamically changing an elements name is appropriate for this situation ?

Comment: yes it's necessary that name="ADD" when a one of these radio buttons is selected, if none are selected it remains an empty value.

Comment: no luck with your suggestion either

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see you don't have any hidden element with name `opt2`. Did you mean `OptionName2`?

Also, it's not correct the method you're using to change the name.

Try with this

```
$(":hidden[name='OptionName2']").attr("name", "ADD");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple javascript for this..

Just add `id="changehid"` to your hidden field.

Then you can use this function to change it:

```
function change() {
document.getElementById('changehid').name = "ADD";
}
```

Cheers

Evert

**EDIT**

Here's the code : http://jsfiddle.net/hCnyd/3/
I tested it with Safari Inspector, and it adds the name.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXjIE.png

Comment: It works.. i just tried it.. I added a link to the answer where you can find the code...

Comment: wow something must be going on here, cause I copy/pasted your code and it's not working when I try it.

Not sure if this matters but it's on a WP page.

Comment: *EDIT* I have created a straight HTML page and it's still not working. So I have to be doing something wrong???

Comment: I don't know.. When i test the code (you can see the preview,) it works. Just copy the code from JSFiddle.. This must work..

Comment: hmmmm I'll keep messing with it, but yeah I copy/pasted straight from JSFiddle

Comment: Sorry, but thats everything i can do... On JSFiddle it works, so i really don't understand why it shouldn't work in a html file..

Comment: I appreciate your help!! I'll keep at it however.